# In C# open the web browser and capture the output

Tags: c#

From C# console application I need to open the web browser and i want the output. This is the server name in the link. If internet explorer displays nothing then it means server is up. If I get internet explorer cannot display the webpage then it means server is down.

Below is the code to open the IE

```
    Process.Start("https://foo.com");
```

If internet explorer shows an empty page then server is up else server down.

And want to know how the browser closes automatically?

Comment: That's like travelling from London to Paris via Sydney. There are better ways...

Comment: Look into System.Net.WebClient for one.

Answer (score 6):

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string pageData;
    try
    {
        pageData = client.DownloadString(yourAddress);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //something went wrong. Maybe the site is down?
    }
    //does pageData have expected content?
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this but console application is closing , its not showing any exception

Comment: I am expecting my result in two ways only , 1) it shows nothing if server is up 2) if server is down it shows internet explorer cannot display the page

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just need to get the value of a web page, you should use something more lightweight, for example, HttpClient (http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/the-new-net-httpclient-class/). This way you won't have to worry about cleaning up external processes like internet explorer.
2. If you insist on using IE for this, Process.Start(string) returns an instance of System.Diagnostics.Process, so you can call `.Close()` on that returned instance.

.

```
var ieProcess = Process.Start("https://foo.com");
bool isServerUp = IsServerUp(ieProcess); 
ieProcess.Close();
```

Comment: Right, it's pseudo code to represent whatever you are trying to do.